# GKMatchRequest playerGroup property not working

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, game-center, gamekit

For my turn-based boardgame I want the player to be able to set the board size to either normal,large or don't care. I created two playergroups ("1" and "2") for the two boardsizes, and set the playergroup for don't care to 0. In the docs it says:

> "When you set the playerGroup property on a match request to 0, then
>   the player can be matched into any waiting match".

But this doesn't seem to be working. Match requests with playergroup 0 are only matched to other match requests with playergroup 0. Has anyone been able to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use player masks for that. In my experience, player group 0 would only match request with player group 0, but not 1 or 2.

Comment: Do you mean player attributes? How would I use those for this? It seems like attributes try to accomplish the opposite of what I'm trying to do.